# Finding the Mean (Average) in C++

Tags: c++, mean

## About the Program

The program is supposed to generate numbers from user input supplied (initial value and the maximum value) to generate a list of numbers ranging within those value. Once completed, the program needs to display the average between all of the numbers displayed.

## My Code

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int INITIAL_VALUE;
    unsigned int MAX_VALUE;

    std::cout << "\n\n\nStarting value: ";
    std::cin >> INITIAL_VALUE;
    std::cout << "\nValue to count to: ";
    std::cin >> MAX_VALUE;

    std::cout << "\n";

    while(INITIAL_VALUE <= MAX_VALUE)
    {
        ++INITIAL_VALUE;
        std::cout << INITIAL_VALUE << ", ";
    }

    // Code to output the average goes here

    std::cin.get();
    std::cin.get();
}
```

I, of course, made an attempt to solve this, but I could not even wrap my head around an explanation. I know to find the **mean** (average) of numbers by simply adding up all of the numbers, then dividing by the amount of numbers; however, I can't think of a way to transfer such a simple equation into C++ syntax. A thorough explanation would be much appreciated, and thanks to everyone in advance.

Comment: Let's start with thinking about adding two numbers together in C++. Do you know how you would do that and store the result?

Comment: You need to keep track of 2 pieces of data (aside from the actual numbers): the running sum (total) and the number of data points.

Comment: This isn't a homework assignment, but yes I would simply take two numbers, add them and then assign them to a variable.

Comment: Why not use a `for` loop instead of `while`?

Comment: I'm mainly confused on how you could add say 0-10,000 up all together. That's my main problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int INITIAL_VALUE;
    unsigned int MAX_VALUE;
    unsigned int sum  = 0;
    unsigned int count;
    double average;

    std::cout << "\n\n\nStarting value: ";
    std::cin >> INITIAL_VALUE;
    std::cout << "\nValue to count to: ";
    std::cin >> MAX_VALUE;

    std::cout << "\n";
    count = MAX_VALUE - INITIAL_VALUE + 1;

    while(INITIAL_VALUE <= MAX_VALUE)
    {
        sum += INITIAL_VALUE;
        ++INITIAL_VALUE;
        std::cout << INITIAL_VALUE << ", ";
    }

    // Code to output the average goes here
    average = 1.0 * sum / count;

    std::cin.get();
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: I know how I would write in, but I don't understand how to count up all of the numbers.

Comment: `sum += INITIAL_VALUE;` the program sum the value iter from `INITIAL_VALUE` to `MAX_VALUE`

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong is you are not keeping track of the sum of all the values. And then you can divide it by the number of values to get the average. So the while loop part should be like

```
double sum = 0.0;
int n = MAX_VALUE - INITIAL_VALUE + 1;
while(INITIAL_VALUE <= MAX_VALUE)
{
    sum += INITIAL_VALUE;
    ++INITIAL_VALUE;
    std::cout << INITIAL_VALUE << ", ";
}

double average = sum/n;
```